# Boost Pointers as a means of an array

Tags: c++, boost

I'm converting C code to an open-source, C++11 style compatible code, which uses boost. (purposefully not used the C++ shared ptr implementation)

I've studied the use of boost shared_ptrs vs unique_ptrs vs. raw pointers as a means of managing memory resources, based on intended ownership, etc.

I'm getting confused though, at the different layers of abstraction at which raw pointers can be used and whether the semantics translate to boost.

I have a templated class that is purposely *composed* of different structs that make use of said structs.

Example:

```
template <typename my_type> class A : public Base_A
{
    ...
    typedef struct B
    {
      float* numbers; 
      my_type* my_types; 
    };
    typedef struct C
    {
      B* B_types; 
    };
}
```

This is where I'm getting confused. Pointers are used to reference contiguous blocks of memory, right? Because with pointers, you can use the [] operator to index into an offset of the reference memory, and so in this way pointers are not just used to reference objects, but also arrays of types as well. But then again, I guess anything you can do with a class you can do with pointers and data structures, right?

So my question is mainly, how does this all translate to boost and how boost controls deallocation of nested data types, such as structs and nested classes?

For example, does if I do, in my main:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> my_a(new A());
```

or even

```
boost::unique_ptr<A> my_a(new A());
```

...when the reference count goes to 0, A get's deallocated, so does that mean that all of the pointers that A is composed of will be followed, and those will then be deallocated? Do I need to provide the virtual destructor that explicitly deletes the atomics? Or do the pointer variables, including float*, for example, need to be weak_ptr's to do that?

Comment: A pointer points to a single address.  That can be the start of an array or a single variable.  Also if you want to array then use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and forget that pointers even exist.

Comment: The smart pointers are not to be used as iterators. It sounds like what you want is a smart iterator.

Comment: As for memory management, there is no hidden magic in the compiler. Memory allocated within each class or struct shall be deallocated in its corresponding destructor.

Comment: @jxh: So only the first element would be deleted then?
Nielk: "shall be deallocated in its corresponding destructor"--is the call to the destructor the thing boost pointers actually take care, rather than the deallocation itself? Do those deallocation calls propagate through an entire vector? A C-style array?

Comment: Hypothetical `shared_iterator` would have a `shared_ptr` to array being indexed. Hypothetical `weak_iterator` would have a `weak_ptr` to array being indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want smart-pointers to arrays you can use

- `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` - this

  - deletes using `delete[]` through the default deleter
  - is specialized to support `operator[]` just like C-style array indexing
- `boost::shared_array` which is like `boost::shared_ptr` but for `T[]` instead of `T*`

That said, a modern C++11 style suggests `boost::array<>` or `std::vector<>` instead